# Cannot connect to Ubuntu using PuTTY after switching Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I have Ubuntu installed on one of my laptops with the GUI disabled. I installed `openssh-server` and tried accessing it from PuTTY from my Windows machine and it was working all fine. Later I had to switch WiFi networks on both Windows and Ubuntu. Switching in Windows was easy but with Ubuntu it took me some time. Now I have both the systems connected to the same network over WiFi. Even the Internet is accessible from the Ubuntu machine using elinks but ssh is not connecting from the Windows machine. Tried reinstalling but no luck. Please help.

Even I am unable to ping the Linux machine from my Windows PC. I tried `ifconfig -a` and got IP address 192.168.0.107 for wlan0. This is visible in the below screenshot:

[image: ifconfig -a output]

I also have Apache on 80 and Tomcat on 8080, but neither is accessible from the LAN, only from within the same PC.

Comment: Please find the image URL here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsEa3.jpg

Comment: You could try re-installing openssh-server with 'sudo apt-get purge openssh-server' and then 'sudo apt-get install openssh-server'.

Comment: Have done that but no luck. I think there is another issue with permission and all. As apache is also not accessible from outside. I have also added the entries for ssh and 80(apache) in iptables. Can you suggest anything else Max Kulik?

Comment: You are trying to access the laptop from Putty on the same local network, correct?

Comment: Yes on the same network.